# Can I use Spring Async and Java8 parallel stream together

Tags: java, java-stream, spring-async

Basically, Using one Scheduler I want to process multiple csv file at same time.
File can have 1 to 10K records in it. I want to process each file parallelly and also if  records>1K, I want to process that file's records parallelly.

Let's say 1OK records with 10 different thread.

My task is to read one DB tables from where I have FTP file path URL. and process those csv files, validate csv data and ultimately save into DB table.

```
List<CSVFileRecords> files = filesRepo.findAll();

files.foreach(file->processFile(file));

@Async
void processFile(file) {
  InputStream i = getStream(file); //download file
  List<Data> data = csvParser.csvToBean(i); //consider 10K records

  List<List<Data>> dataList = getListOfList(data);
    
  dataList.parallelStream().foreach(data-> processData(data));

}

List<Response> processData(data) {
    validate();
    saveAll();
 }
```

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: My question is : Can I use Spring Async and Java8 parallel stream together in one call? How thread allocation will work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it won't work as you are expecting.

because of,  **files.foreach(file->processFile(file));**

good option would be

```java
// 10 - Number of threads

ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

files.foreach(file -> executorService.execute(() -> processFile(file)));
```

Things to note, inside process method you are using parallelStream, that will subsequently create more threads based on the size of data.

A good practice would be, partition your data before processing.